# Tools to detect denormal numbers during execution

Tags: performance, floating-point

I have a program which I suspect is slow due to the presence of denormal numbers. Is there a tool available for Linux which will allow me to monitor the execution of a program and print statistics on whether any denormal numbers were detected during execution?

Comment: You might check the `FE_UNDERFLOW` flag using `fetestexcept`.  I'm not certain whether this is raised when subnormals are generated or when the nearest floating-point number to the computed quantity is a zero.  You can also make your program bomb out when the underflow exception occurs using `feenableexcept`.